# how to work out 3 equations simultaneously

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, linear-programming, quadratics

So i was doing this linear programming question and got stuck on this part, so how do you workout simultaneously
$2x + 3y = 30   $
$(2/3)x + 2y = 16   $
$(16/3)x + 4y = 64$

According to lpsolve we should have y = 4 and x = 9 based on the maximization of cost $120x + 150y = cost$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Solve the first 2 and "plug in" the values of $x$ and $y$ in the third. If the third equation is satisfied, then you have solved the system. If not then either you made an calculation error or the 3 equations don't have a solution.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that before posting this, but when i do that with another combination i get different results. like if i solve 1 and 3 and then i get different values of x and y.

Comment: lary, that's because the three equations together have no solution. There are no values of $x$ and $y$ that fulfill all three equations.

Comment: Are the first 3 equations supposed to be inequalities?

Comment: @JimmyK4542, that would make more sense. lary, why is it called "cost" if it is to be maximized?

Comment: sorry people, i had made a mistake on the first constraint, i have fixed it now. Very beautiful and kind people

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, $x = 9$ and $y = 4$ is not a solution, as you can simply check by entering these values into the first equation: $2x + 5y = 38$, not $46$.

Second, you have three equations in two unknowns, which means your system of equations is overdetermined. If either one of the equations can be constructed from the two others by linear combination, then you have a solution, or it cannot, then there is no solution at all.

It turns out there is no solution. The first two equations together have the solution $x = 18$ and $y = 2$, but these values do not fulfill the third equation.

The cost function never comes into play.

---

Assuming these are not equations but inequalities ($\leq$), and assuming there is a nonnegativity constraint ($x \geq 0$ and $y \geq 0$), the problem makes more sense. We can visualize it by plotting the "cost" function over $x$ and $y$, and the borders of the areas defined by the inequalities on top of it:

[image]

The three equations correspond to the blue, green, and red line, respectively, the grayscale plot in the background shows the "cost" function.

Because the "cost" function increases with both $x$ and $y$, the optimum has to lie *on* one of the lines (though not the blue line, since it lies completely behind the two others). Because the "cost" is linear, it has a gradient in a single direction, $(15, 12)$, which means sliding along either line we can always make it larger. Consequently, the optimum has to lie at the intersection of the green and red line, or, it has to be the joint solution of the 2nd and 3rd equation.

Solving these leads to $x = 8$ and $y = 5\frac13$, at a "cost" of 1760.

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate it. The problem was the first constraint, which i have fixed

Comment: @lary, you're welcome. If the answer helped, consider upvoting and/or accepting it.

Comment: you said "Consequently, the optimum has to lie at the intersection of the green and red line, or, it has to be the joint solution of the 2nd and 3rd equation." How do you determine this.

Comment: The explanation is "Because the "cost" is linear, it has a gradient in a single direction, (15,12), which means sliding along either line we can always make it larger." You slide along one line until you meet the other, which means another constraint keeps you from going further.

Comment: Sorry, i should of been more specific with my question. I meant how do you determine choosing the red and green lines as they hold the optimum, also how do we know the blue lies behind the 2 others

Comment: @lary, that the blue lies behind the others you can simply see in the visualization. Algorithmically? I guess one would make a list of all intersection points between all pairs of lines, and then check which of them actually fulfill the constraints. The intersection between the red and the blue does not fulfill the green constraints, so it is out. So we are left with the intersection between green and red.